# socket connection not establishing at flutter end with socket_io_client library

Tags: node.js, flutter, sockets, dart, websocket

I am trying to develop a flutter app that connects to the web socket backend using socket io.
A socket connection is successfully at node js end but tries with flutter connection not establishing.
Flutter example:

```
  Socket socket;
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    connectToSocket();
  }

  connectToSocket() {
    socket = io('http://xyx.com/', <String, dynamic>{
      'autoConnect': false,
    });
    socket.connect();
  }
```

server end :

```
const app = require('express')()
const http = require('http').createServer(app)
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Node Server is running. Yay!!")
})
//Socket Logic
const socketio = require('socket.io')(http)
socketio.on("connection", (userSocket) => {
    console.log("Socket connected", userSocket.id)
    userSocket.on("send_message", (data) => {
        userSocket.broadcast.emit("receive_message", data)
    })
})
const PORT=5577
http.listen(PORT)
```

output :
Socket connected TrnjhDEZyb-nsJmoAAAA
with node js: socket connection is successful and output at server end socket connected.

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const socket = io.connect('http://xyx.com/');
```

**But at flutter the end no connection establishment.**

Comment: Hi did you solve it, facing same problem

Comment: for Flutter: use socket_io_client
use property 'transports': ['webscoket']
link:https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client.
Why polling is not supported
'transports': ['polling'] does not support in Flutter, by default this library was designed for dart web, but dart web is not popular than Flutter; the polling mechanism is ported from Socket.io JS, which is using Ajax way to implement, but it's not allowed in dart:io library.

Comment: from backend, it will be used only transports': ['webscoket']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import 'package:socket_io/socket_io.dart';
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart'

Socket socket = io('http://xyx.com/', <String, dynamic>{
    'transports': ['websocket'],
    'autoConnect': false,
  });
socket.connect();
```